# TextInputEditText hint is covered by box outline

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

I'm using `TextInputEditText`s as text entry, and when I select them, the hint moves up as it should, but is covered by the outline of the box.  Does anyone know why that would be happening?

**Photo**:
[image]

**Code**:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_layout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/grey"
        android:theme="@style/OutlinedEditText"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/blue"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/blue"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cover_art">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:hint="@string/title"
            android:inputType="textCapWords" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remove** in the `TextInputEditText`

```
android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
```

In this way you are adding a margin between the main container (`TextInputLayout`) and the `EditText`

[image]

Use:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_layout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:hint="...."
        ...
        >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:inputType="textCapWords" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are placing `android:hint="@string/title"` attribute in `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText`.

The `android:hint="@string/title"` should be placed in `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_layout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/grey"
        android:theme="@style/OutlinedEditText"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/blue"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/blue"
        android:hint="@string/title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cover_art">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:inputType="textCapWords" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```